# Trim commas with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a list of keywords like below and some keyword lists in the database have a leading or trailing `,`

```
keyword,keyword,keyword,keyword,
```

How do I trim the leading and/or trailing `,` using mysql?

I have tried using `trim` but can't seem to get it to work on an `UPDATE`, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How exactly have you been using `TRIM()` in your `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: do you have to do the trim in the DB when updating the record?  I would normally do this in the programming language.

Comment: Yes so would I, but as this database is already quite large. I didn't fancy running over ALL my scripts again to populate it

Comment: Can you provide us with more detail information regarding the `UPDATE` that you cannot get to work?

Comment: Umm, refp you answered my question perfectly. I left a comment. I just needed to know how the TRIM worked

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
 TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM ',keyword,keyword,')
```

The above would return `'keyword,keyword'`.

`BOTH` can be replaced with either `LEADING` or `TRAILING` if you just want to trim on one side of the string.

**Documentation**

- [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 11.5 String Functions :: TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

---

There shouldn't be any problem using `TRIM` in an `UPDATE` query, but without the query in question we cannot offer any specific help. But `TRIM` is just like any other function available, it takes a set of parameters and returns a value.

---

**Sample post-insert query to fix fields with trailing `','`**

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `keywords` = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM `keywords`);
```

Comment: TRIM([{BOTH | LEADING | TRAILING} [remstr] FROM] str), TRIM([remstr FROM] str)  
it will be nice if you add this row into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET column = TRIM( BOTH  ',' FROM  'a,b,c,d,' )
```

That one worked for me. cf: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim