# remove commas from a strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two rows in column like this:

1. , Josiah Tongari Street, Labone, Accra Metropolitan, Greater Accra, Ghana
2. ,  , Accra, Greater Accra, Ghana

So I want to remove first `comma` from first one and remove first two from 2nd one. I want output like this egxample:

1. Josiah Tongari Street, Labone, Accra Metropolitan, Greater Accra, Ghana
   2.Accra, Greater Accra, Ghana

Thanks

Comment: @Sandeep Singh share your code what you had done yet

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: use regex. thats is a string manipulation, better do that with restitution tool rather than DB

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(','+ fulladdress + ',',',,','') from businessmaster where fulladdress like ',%' or fulladdress like ', ,%'

Comment: i have right the above code but it can not replace 2 condition

Comment: i'm using sql server 2012

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545367/trim-commas-with-mysql). You can use `TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM [yourString])` in MySQL.

Comment: in the above code it replace first comma but it can not replace first two comma.

Comment: what happend guys, did u get the right query?

Answer (score 1):

First, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutely yes!**
After reading that, you should normalize your database.

If you can't normalize your database, then you can use `STUFF` and `PATINDEX` to remove the first commas.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col varchar(100) 
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
('a, b,c'), 
(', d, e,f'), 
(', , g, h,i, j')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  STUFF(col, 1, PATINDEX('%[^, ]%', col)-1, '') As col
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
col
a, b,c
d, e,f
g, h,i, j
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)